# Fitting to data with a Bernoulli (I think) distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, curve-fitting

I have a series of data to which I want to fit my model. The model predicts the probability of success at a given value of x. I have a single data point at a number of points in this space. As I have a single point which is either pass or fail with a certain probability I believe I should fit using a Bernoulli maximum likelihood fit, is this correct? So i have a likelihood function which looks something like
$$L(\theta,x) = \Pi^{n}_{i} \theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i}$$
where n are my data points? This is just different enough to the usual Binomial likelihood case to have completely thrown me.

Comment: Isn't $\prod_i^n\theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i}$ the same as $\theta^{\sum_i x_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_i x_i} = \theta^y(1-\theta)^{n-y}$ where $y = \sum_i x_i$ is a binomial $(n,\theta)$ random variable?

Comment: Wouldn't $y$ have the distribution ${n \choose k} \theta^y (1 - \theta)^{n-y}$ if $y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

Comment: @SachaEpskamp What is the relationship between $y$ and $k$?  In any case, the _probability mass function_ of $y$ is irrelevant.  The _likelihood_ of the _observation_ or data $$x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$ is exactly what Bowler stated it to be, and it _is_ essentially a binomial likelihood.  The extra constant factor $\binom{n}{y}$ (remember that $y$ is a function of the data $x$ and is thus fixed) that you have included makes no difference: the value of $\theta$ that maximizes $\theta^y(1-\theta)^{n-y}$ is the same as that which maximizes $\binom{n}{y}\theta^y(1-\theta)^{n-y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is a vector with independent measurements of a single variable which can be pass or fail, then this is the likelihood indeed, except that I think $L(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \theta)$ would be the proper notation.

EDIT: the binomial distribution is based on the sumscore. It would be the proper distribution if you were using $y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: Thining about it I asked a yes/no quesiton so this does actually answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) (or at least the likelihood that is maximized in logistic regression). If the wiki isn't enough, search for MLE fitting of logistic regression on Google.

Comment: Thanks, logistic regression looks interesting its definitely a possibility.